# Android: How to get logging information if device freezes / hangs?

Tags: android, logging, freeze

I have written an app and on some devices, using the app freezes the system. My main problem is, that I do not get any log information, because as soon as the device is frozen, logging completely stops and obviously the crash-reports normally would be generated after the crash, which does not work, because the device is frozen.

I have attached the device to my laptop via adb (via USB) and logcat everything, but the logging just stops as the device freezes. I have also checked all possible log locations (I used [this reference](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26340/is-there-a-good-way-to-find-out-why-an-android-phone-hangs%22%5Dthis%20reference)) and could not find anything.

Since the app crashes only on about 10% of all devices (the devices are identical and have the same firmware) I need to test the app on the device and cannot use the emulator. However if the app crashes, I can relieable reproduce the crash using adb monkey. On the other 90% adb monkey won't crash the device.

Is there anything else I can log / test / check? Is there a way to get a memory dump, once the device is frozen?

Although I don't think this is relevant: The device is a XORO 9718DR tablet and the device is rooted. The app is written by myself and not available in the market. It mainly uses only Buttons, TextView, ImageView, HttpClientConnection, Threads, AsyncTasks and other "normal" Android stuff. It even does not use the webview.

Comment: why dont you trace the freeze to some part of code ? How is anyone to help you by your wall of text ?

Comment: The device freezes at different parts of the code. Meanwhile I could freeze the device with different apps as well. The basic question is: Are there some other logging possibities or is there a way to get a memory dump?

Comment: What kinda app is this ? Talk about that. May be we can give you a few hints for memory utilization. Is it a game ? Does it have too many drawables ? Are you resizing any ? Are you using bitmaps ? Are you downloading a 1Gb json xml :) ?

Comment: Unfortunately the app is not publically available and/or in any store. Basically the app displays some images on the screen on which you can click. The clicks are recorded, stored in a SQLite database and (if there are enough records in the database) transferred to a server.

All resources I load are between 512kB and 2MB, most of them PNG images. I have a json, but it is less then 4kB. The images are not resized and there are between 15 to 50 images. The images are not scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Use DDMS to trace heap memory [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html).

In your manifest file put `debuggable=true`. Build your app and install it on your device, run DDMS. Select your app from the list, and enable Heap from the toolbar button.

Comment: Good idea, but when the device freezes, DDMS only says "Device disconnected" and does not show any further information. Therefore that solution does not work (unfortunately).

Comment: You need to trace the growth of memory utilization and memory leak when it happens. Not attempt to dissect a dead cow dude.. :) Who said tracing memory leaks was easy ?

Comment: Ok, not easy... However: what information I gave makes you think it is a memory problem? I mean: I don't really know where the problem is and if anything I said makes you think of a memory leak, then I have a better way of tracing down the problem.